# Why is Ember/handlebars.js adding 'app/' to the front of my template files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

When Load my Rails ember app I get a blank screen because ember is trying to find my application and index templates at

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['application] and Ember.TEMPLATES['index']
```

But when I run Ember.TEMPLATES in the console it brings up all the templates as 'app/application' and 'app/index'.

So ember is looking for /application.hbs but cant find it because for some reason the templates are listed as app/application. But the actual file structure of app is:

```
assets -> javascripts -> app -> templates -> application.hbs and index.hbs
```

So their direct parent is not 'app/'

[image]

Any idea why its doing this and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know where that syntax error is coming from?

Comment: yes, its coming from the i18n.js file. https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

Comment: When I get rid of the file the syntax error goes away, but still nothing renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember-Rails compiles the handlebars from the assets/javascripts directory directly.
You have two options, modify your hierarchy to not use the `app` folder.

Or set `config.handlebars.templates_root = 'app'` in your `application.rb`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I've tried adding 
config.handlebars.templates_root = 'app' to application.rb and it does nothing.

Comment: I got it. I added that and then had to rake assets:clean. Thanks so much!